# How to delete the PosReady 2009 upgrade regkey in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry

It is well know that adding these lines

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\WPA\PosReady]
"Installed"=dword:00000001
```

to a Windows XP SP3 installation, will allow it to install updates designed for Windows PosReady 2009. The problem is that after the installation of those updates, one cannot delete that registry key.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Boot "[Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/%7Epnh/ntpasswd/)"

Mount the partition with your windows installation, select the full option, change to the regkey and delete it. Then exit the program and write the changes back to disk.
Boot back to Windows and the regkey is gone.

All my tries to delete it from within Windows failed.